# Spotify MP3 preview link not working with AVPlayer

Tags: avplayer, spotify

I am having an issue with Spotify preview links, they are not playing using `AVPlayer`.

```
    var aSongURL: String = String(format: "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/2d933f6474345c8af7e164356f30f450d0fc1309?cid=5e9ac4fc700442599e05f987a9cb1d4a")
    var aPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: NSURL(string: aSongURL)! as URL)
    var anAudioStreamer: AVPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: aPlayerItem)
    anAudioStreamer.play()
```

---

It's a MP3, why is it not supported by `AVPlayer`, any ideas?

Comment: Is this code for an iOS, macOS or tvOS application?

Comment: its for iOS v11.1+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34563570/2740582). It worked for me for your URL.

Comment: i've already tried it , its not playing this url by Spotify `"https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/2d933f6474345c8af7e164356f30f450d0fc1309?cid=5e9ac4fc700442599e05f987a9cb1d4a"` wired

Comment: Have you enabled App Transport Security(ATS)  in your info.plist file? I tried playing that exact URL, and it worked for me.

Comment: not working i got this error `CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sync = syna;
}`